# Read this file and create a dictionary with keys of the type tuple and values of the type float

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, tuples

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz try this as list and string and then dictionary and also tuple

Comment: language???????

Comment: Yeah, you are asking this question for which language?

Comment: python language

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: There is no clear problem statement. You are expected to have made a fair attempt to answer this question yourself, before asking about any specific problems that arise. Please include the code that you have written.

Comment: from sys import argv
nameofprogram,filename=argv
count=0
try:
 fhandler=open(filename)
except:
 print 'doesnot exist'
 exit()

for line in fhandler:
 count=count+1
 list=line.split()
 print list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(filename) as f:
    d = {tuple(x.split(':')[0].strip().split(',')): float(x.split(':')[1].strip()) for x in f}
```

This is a (fairly complex) dictionary comprehension.  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/